# Change Default branch in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I accidentally pushed my local master to a branch called origin on gitlab and now it is the default. Is there a way to rename this branch or set a new master branch to master?

Comment: if you're maintaining a Drupal contributed module, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/287518/as-maintainer-change-the-default-branch-of-a-contributed-module-on-gitlab

Answer (score 206, accepted):

in the GitLab Enterprise Edition 12.2.0-pre you have to use following:
`Setting` → `Repository` → `Default Branch` ( expand it) and change the default branch Here

[image]

Comment: They keep moving it so I have to keep changing my correct answer. All other high voted answers were correct at the time they were posted.

Comment: This applies as of February 2021. Until the next change...

Comment: Hello from 14.0! Although they changed it, so it uses sentence case, the option is still on the same spot.

Comment: All the branches appear in the dropdown... except the one I want. Figures.

Answer (score 126):

In 8.0+ it looks like this was moved into the project.  If you open your project and go to the gear icon on the right, then "Edit Project" you can set the default branch for the project.

Comment: Dear reader, look at other answers for references to newer version of gitlab

Comment: thanks @bigdatamann I've updated the correct answer to the most updated current version

Answer (score 126):

To change default branch in GitLab:
1. Settings > General > General project settings > Expand
2. Default Branch > Change your project default branch
3. Save changes

[image]

Answer (score 61):

For gitlab v10+ (as of Sept 2018), this has moved to settings-> repository -> default branch

[image]

As stated by @Luke this is still valid as on **4/1/2021**

Comment: As of March 2019, this is still the correct answer!

Comment: Also not "Settings", "Expand one of the many options in the main content area", but "Settings", "Repository" (in the sidebar). AKA https://gitlab.com/you/your-repository/settings/repository

Comment: This is still correct as of Jan 4th, 2021. (GitLab Enterprise Edition 13.8.0)

Answer (score 58):

To change the default branch in Gitlab 7.7.2:

- Click Settings in the left-hand bar
- Change the Default Branch to the desired branch
- Click Save Changes.

Comment: Why is this obvious option so hard for me to find too?

Comment: GitLab Community Edition 8.8.5 does not have "Settings" in the left-hand bar.

Comment: They changed the UI so I've changed the correct answer to @Mason

Answer (score 20):

In Gitlab version v11.4.4-ee, you can:

1. Setting
2. Repository
3. Default Branch

[image]

Answer (score 17):

1. Settings
2. General
3. General Project Settings

[image: Setting the default branch]

Answer (score 13):

In the latest GitLab Community Edition version 9.2.2.:

1. You have to click on 'Settings' tab located at right most on tabs
   panel after opening the project.
2. Under 'Settings' you will get section 'Default Branch' dropdown
   which will give you all branches for the repository. Select the desired branch.
3. Scroll down to hit green colored 'Save changes' button located just
   after 'Project Avatar'.

Please refer image below:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

See also [GitLab 13.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/11/22/gitlab-13-6-released/#customize-the-initial-branch-name-for-new-projects-within-a-group) (November 2020)

> ### Customize the initial branch name for new projects within a group
>
> When creating a new Git repository, the first branch created is named `master` by default.
>
> In coordination with the Git project, broader community, and other Git vendors, GitLab has been listening to the development community’s feedback on determining a more descriptive and inclusive name for the default branch, and is now offering users options to change the name of the default branch name for their repositories.
>
> Previously, we shipped the ability to [customize the initial branch name at the instance-level](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/221013) and as part of 13.6, GitLab now allows group administrators to configure the default branch name for new repositories created through the GitLab interface.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#custom-initial-branch-name) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/221014).

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/uploads/2959ef65431bf4ffac659992360d6d8d/image.png]

---

GitLab 13.9 (Feb 2021) details:

> ### [Git default branch name change](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/02/22/gitlab-13-9-released/#git-default-branch-name-change)

> Every Git repository has an initial branch. It’s the first branch to be created automatically when you create a new repository.
> By default, this initial branch is named `master`.
>
> **Git version 2.31.0 (scheduled for release March 15, 2021) will change the default branch name in Git from `master` to `main`**.
>
> In coordination with the Git project and the broader community, GitLab will be changing the default branch name for new projects on both our SaaS (GitLab.com) and self-managed offerings starting with GitLab 14.0.
> This will not affect existing projects.
>
> For more information, see the related [epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/3600) and the Git [mailing list discussion](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqqa6vf437i.fsf@gitster.c.googlers.com/T/#t).
>
> **Deprecation date: Apr 22, 2021**

---

As promise, with GitLab 13.11 (Apr. 2021):

> ### [Git default branch name change](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/22/gitlab-13-11-released/#git-default-branch-name-change)
>
> Every Git repository has an initial branch.
> It’s the first branch to be created automatically when you create a new repository.
>
> By default, this initial branch is named `master`.
> [Future Git versions](https://lore.kernel.org/git/pull.656.v4.git.1593009996.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/) will change the default branch name in Git from `master` to `main`.
>
> In coordination with the Git project and the broader community, [GitLab will be changing the default branch name](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/223789) for new projects on both our SaaS (GitLab.com) and self-managed offerings starting with GitLab 14.0.
> This will not affect existing projects.
>
> GitLab has already introduced changes that allow users to change the default branch name both at the [instance-level](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/default.html#instance-level-custom-initial-branch-name) (for self-managed users) and at the [group-level](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#use-a-custom-name-for-the-initial-branch) (for both SaaS and self-managed users).
> We encourage users to make use of these features to set default branch names on new projects.
>
> For more information, see the related epic and related blog post.

Comment: This was helpful, as was the screenshot at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57492760/470749

Comment: @Ryan Thank you. I forgot the screenshot indeed. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Settings > Repository > Default Branch

[image]

Answer (score 2):

December, 2022

settings >> repository >> Branch defaults :: expand and set your desire branch.

Answer (score 1):

First I needed to remote into my server with ssh. If someone has a non ssh way of doing this please post.

I found my bare repositories at

```
cd /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/group-name/project-name.git
```

used

```
git branch
```

to see the wrong active branch

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master
```

to change the master to to be the branch called master then use the web interface and "git branch" to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

In Gitlab CE 9.0, You can change the default branch from the Settings Tab in a repository's header.

Answer (score 1):

For GitLab 11.5.0-ee, go to
`https://gitlab.com/<username>/<project name>/settings/repository`.

You should see:

`Default Branch`

Select the branch you want to set as the default for this project. All merge requests and commits will automatically be made against this branch unless you specify a different one.

Click Expand, select a branch, and click Save Changes.