# First branch pushed in GitLab becomes default

Tags: git, gitlab

Why does the first branch name pushed to remote in GitLab become the default branch? Is that why GitLab instructs to push an empty README.md file to master when working with a new repository? Or is it supposed to work like that?

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ the first branch pushed become the default branch? At first it's the only one there, and why would the default branch change unless you ask it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sort of a general information on how to set up your default branch with GitLab

> ```
> 1. Click "Settings" in the left-hand bar
> 2. Change the default branch to the desired branch
> 3. Click "Save Changes"
> ```

This should change the default branch.

Comment: This works in In 8.0+ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987216/change-default-branch-in-gitlab