# GitLab : Can not find "default description template for merge request"

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

I created a project and the role is Maintainer.

When I want to create "default description template for merge request", I can not find text area.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1jyy.png)

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I do not want to use template(`.gitlab/merge_request_templates/`).

I have create`.gitlab/merge_request_templates/Default.md`.When I create new merge request, I can see this template.

But I want to have a default value without selecting any template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OP 楊筱誼](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12716094/%E6%A5%8A%E7%AD%B1%E8%AA%BC) confirms in the comments:

> "Setting default template" is only available if you have a Starter (or higher) license for a self-managed installation of GitLab or Bronze for GitLab.com.
>
> My trial license seems to have expired, so it cannot be displayed.

---

> I can not find text area.

Precisely because, as described in the official documentation "[Description templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html)", you do not have yet created a `.md` file in the  `.gitlab/merge_request_templates/` directory of your repository.

Once you have created, committed and push that file, *then* you will see that field:

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/img/description_templates_merge_request_settings.png]

> I do not want to use template(.gitlab/merge_request_templates/).

Then... you won't see that field.

Don't forget the visibility:

> The visibility of issues and/or merge requests should be set to either “`Everyone with access`” or “`Only Project Members`” in your project’s `Settings / Visibility, project features, permissions section`, otherwise the template text areas won’t show.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have created ".gitlab/merge_request_templates/Code_Review_Checklist.md". Still can't see text area.

Comment: @楊筱誼 Did you have pushed it? On the master branch?

Comment: Yes. I have pushed it.

Comment: @楊筱誼 To the master branch? Is master your default branch for your repository GitLab? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57660969/6309)

Comment: I have pushed it to the master branch. My default branch is master. When I create new merge request, I can see this template. But I want to have a default value without selecting any template. Thanks for your help... (☍﹏⁰)

Comment: @楊筱誼 Is the visibility properly set? "The visibility of issues and/or merge requests should be set to either “Everyone with access” or “Only Project Members” in your project’s Settings / Visibility, project features, permissions section, otherwise the template text areas won’t show"

Comment: My Project visibility is private. The visibility of merge requests is "Only Project Members".  I even modified the visibility, and no text areas appeared.

Comment: @楊筱誼 Strange: that might warrant a support ticket: https://support.gitlab.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lots. :")

Comment: @楊筱誼 Let me know if you have any answer from the GitLab support team.

Comment: Hi @VonC, "Setting default template" is only available if you have a Starter (or higher) license for a self-managed installation of GitLab or Bronze for GitLab.com. My trial license seems to have expired, so it cannot be displayed.

Comment: @楊筱誼 Thank you for your feedback: I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: ah, I was missing the dot '.' before gitlab